# How do I determine the number of uwsgi max-requests?

Tags: uwsgi

uwsgi option

```
master = true

processes = 4

threads = 2

socket = /tmp/%(project).sock

chmod-socket = 666

vacuum = true

socket-timeout = 10

listen = 1024

enable-threads = true

reload-mercy = 30

reload-on-rss = 1400

max-worker-lifetime = 3600

harakiri = 40
```

I would like to add `max-requests` from the options currently in use. Looking at other usage examples, it seems to be setting `max-requests` of 1000 to 5000.

[image]

I have 8 `workers` because I run 2 servers with the same specification using aws elb.

There are 40,000 requests every 5 minutes with the most users. What is the best way to find the optimal values ​​for `max-requests`?

If set it to 5000 as in the other examples, I think the worker restarts every 5 minutes. If so, it seems to be a problem.